# Are "whence" and "whilst" still used today or are they fully outmoded?

Tags: word-usage

I don't come across them in writing anymore, unless it's poetry.

Comment: Amusingly, I think that one of the SE auto comments actually uses "whilst"... Something along the lines of "Whilst this may answer the question..."

Comment: *Whilst* is far more common in BrE than AmE.

Comment: @StoneyB I speak AusE and am a Gen Z. I tend to use "whilst". "Whence", however... very outdated I think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see them that often, but they are still used occasionally.

From an article published 13 hours ago in [Herald and Review](http://herald-review.com/high-school/cg/rounding-up-national-honor/article_fcfbedcf-740c-509c-b0d6-77babbd25d7c.html):

> But no matter **whence** it came, Sierra's first love has led her to unexpected heights, even before she heads to Lake Land College this month to study animal science.

From an article title this month, in [Metro](http://metro.co.uk/2016/08/09/video-granit-xhaka-pranked-by-arsenal-players-whilst-sleeping-on-team-coach-6056701/) :

> "Granit Xhaka pranked by Arsenal players **whilst** sleeping on team
>   coach" --

Comment: +1  I took the liberty of putting your links in a more compact form.

Comment: I would have done that, but I don't know how to.

Comment: See the answer of @Sue to this Meta question http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/688/purely-technical-question-about-putting-a-link-in-a-q-or-an-a